# How to customize attrs field hash

Tags: joblib, python-attrs

I'd like to use a Numpy array as a field value while keeping my `attrs` class hashable. For that purpose, I found [joblib's `hash()`](https://joblib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/joblib.hash.html) function to be a good means of hashing Numpy arrays. Is there any possibility to keep using `attrs`'s default hash function while specifying manually how to hash each field, e.g. with something like

```py
import attrs
import numpy as np
from joblib import hash as jbhash

@attrs.frozen
class MyClass:
    field: np.ndarray = attrs.field(hash=jbhash)  # I know this doesn't work at the moment
```

or do I have to write my own `__hash__()`?

**Notes:**

- I omitted a converter making `field` non-writeable for brevity)
- Context: My goal is to use this data class as an argument of a function memoized using `functools.lru_cache()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that's [currently not possible](https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/blob/98aa688501ca65d7ab83f0b0f1b7ce0b3302a0bf/src/attr/_make.py#L1623-L1694), primarily because nobody ever asked for it. Hashing is usually something people don't care about until it breaks...

The feature request is tracked at https://github.com/python-attrs/attrs/issues/1076